flick_video_player when back show black screen
I'm using the flick_video_player package in my Flutter app to play videos. The video plays fine, but when I rotate the device (left or right) and then navigate back to the previous page, a black screen is shown. If I don't rotate the device, everything works fine.
Here is the code I'm using:
import 'package:flick_video_player/flick_video_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:visibility_detector/visibility_detector.dart';

class PlayVideo extends StatefulWidget {
  const PlayVideo({super.key, required this.videoURL});

  final String videoURL;

  @override
  State<PlayVideo> createState() => _PlayVideoState();
}

class _PlayVideoState extends State<PlayVideo> {
  late FlickManager flickManager;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    flickManager = FlickManager(
      videoPlayerController: VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(
        Uri.parse(widget.videoURL),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    flickManager.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: VisibilityDetector(
        key: ObjectKey(flickManager),
        onVisibilityChanged: (visibility) {
          if (visibility.visibleFraction == 0 && mounted) {
            flickManager.flickControlManager?.autoPause();
          } else if (visibility.visibleFraction == 1) {
            flickManager.flickControlManager?.autoResume();
          }
        },
        child: Center(
          child: AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 16 / 10,
            child: FlickVideoPlayer(
              flickManager: flickManager,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


You need to set the device orientation properties:
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
   body: FlickVideoPlayer(
     flickManager: flickManager,
     preferredDeviceOrientation: [
       DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
       DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft
     ],
     systemUIOverlay: [],
     flickVideoWithControls: FlickVideoWithControls(
       controls: LandscapePlayerControls(),
     ),
   ),
 );
}

